# Zurb Foundation Clearing - Fullscreen issue on Chrome. Bug?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I implemented Zurb Foundation's Clearing on an e-commerce website and I'm facing an issue under Chrome when the fullscreen is launched. The issue is even present on the Zurb Docs where the first image is shown on the bottom-right corner of the screen.

You can see right [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/clearing.php) on their gallery example (remember you need to run on Chrome)

If the link is not working or the issue isn't showing to you, please check [this link](http://d.pr/i/lNWy) of a screenshot I took from their website.

I posted on support but they don't seem to be there following feedback.

Maybe anyone found the way to solve this...would you share with me?

Thanks!!

Comment: I tested it on a screen resolution 1366 x 768 and it works fine in Chrome version 23.0.1271.97 m. What's the screen resolution you have?

Comment: 1920 x 1080 I have some other people testing it and all faced the same issue.

Comment: The following is a screen shot of full screen @ 1366X768 Chrome version 23.0.1271.97 m on Windows7 64 bit. http://postimage.org/image/mydk7u4kb/

Comment: OK, looks good, but I still having the issue, and still have to resolve. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: just in case, https://groups.google.com/d/topic/foundation-framework-/A7cigJsV6m8/discussion these guys are reporting the problem as well.